# send dictionary through segue in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary declared in my first view controller and i want to pass the dictionary through the segue to the detail view controller, the only problem is that i'm not entirely sure how to achieve this?

Dictionary in first view Controller:

```
    var items = [NSDictionary]()
```

Detail View Controller:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var Pr : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var items = [NSDictionary]()` - this is array of elements of `NSDictionary`. If you wish `NSDictionary` - declare it without square braces:

```
var items = NSDictionary()
```

Now, in `DetailViewController` you should declare property, that will able hold passed dictionary. It can be exactly same named:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var items = NSDictionary()
    /* ... */
}
```

Now you can use `prepareForSegue` for passing dictionary (you should use segue identifier, setted in storyboard):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegue" {
        let Pr : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        Pr.items = items
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your DetailViewController add a variable called items.

```
class DetailViewController : UIViewController {
    var items : NSDictionary?
}
```

Then in your prepare for segue set the value.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destView : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
        destView.items = self.items
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty low quality answer. Your `items` (or `item`?) property of `DetailViewController` will not accept `items` from OP class; If there are other segues to other `DetailViewController`, they will probably don't want to have this items

Comment: OP says he has a dictionary but actually has an array of dictioniaries - so I assumed he just typed it out wrong. Should've mentioned it though. OP says he wants to pass the dictionary from FirstViewController to DetailViewController. That's exactly what this does.

Comment: When you assume something, you should point it in your answer I believe. Your code does nothing, because it will not compile even with your assumes. Do not write fast and short and often full of mistakes answers, try to make quality instead.